# How To Modify This Code In python to return/print all positive numbers not just one

Tags: python, list, loops, printing, return-value

The `positive_numbers` function should return a list containing numbers that are non-negative (>=0).
However, currently, it returns only the `[3]` instead of a list of values.

I tried different ways to make this work I'm currently a beginner in python and I don't have anyone to ask that's why I'm sorry if this is too basic for you just want to learn and see my mistake

```
def positive_numbers(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        result = []
        result = result + [number]
        if number < 0:
            continue
    return result
```

**Expected**: The function should return a list of numbers

**Actual**: returns list with the only value being 3

**Error**: The call `positive_numbers([1, 2, 3])` should return `[1, 2, 3]`, but it returned `[3]`

Comment: `result` should  be outside of `for` loop

Comment: the answers below describe what goes wrong. i'd suggest you just use: `[number for number in numbers if number >= 0]`. this list-comprehension will create a list of the positive numbers.

Comment: @DaruisTV You say strictly positive, but then proceed to write '<0'. You mean '>0', right? And not including 0?

Comment: @brentertainer In this scenario I want to include 0 so >= 0 would be the best choice but I'm still learning and I appreciate all the feedback and solution ideas to make this better :)

Answer (score 1):

You reset the list each iteration of the loop because of `result = []`.

Try this:

```
def positive_numbers(numbers):
    result = []
    for number in numbers:
        if number > 0:
            result = result + [number]
    return result
```

Also, debugging would make this very clear. Try to debug your code to get a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `result` outside of your for loop.

```
def positive_numbers(numbers):
    result = []
    for number in numbers:
        if number < 0:
            continue
        result.append(number)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You have all of the pieces, just not necessarily in the right order. Here is an amended version:

```
def positive_numbers(numbers):                                                                      
    result = []                                                                                     
    for number in numbers:                                                                          
        if number < 0:                                                                              
            continue                                                                                
        result = result + [number]                                                                  
    return result
```

With `result = []` inside the for loop as you had it, you were emptying the result on each iteration. Then you were unconditionally adding the number to the list instead of checking if it is negative first. In this amended first, the loop skips to the next number if the current number is not non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, you are setting `results` no a new empty string at every iteration of your for loop. Also, the `if` statement does not make any change, since by the time is evaluated, the new number is appended to the result.
So the minimal working change is:

```
def positive_numbers(numbers):
    result = []
    for number in numbers:
        if number  0:
            continue
        result = result + [number]
    return result
```

Besides, note that you could use a list comprehension for that:

```py
positive_numbers = [number for number in numbers if number >= 0]
```

Or using `filter`:

```py
positive_numbers = list(filter(lambda num: num>=0, numbers))
```

Note that in the latter case, if you don't need your output to be a list but an iterable, you can remove the `list(...)` part

Comment: Didn't even note that. Thank you, I have fixed it